# Error: file type is Invalid in @ajith-ab / react-native-receive-sharing-intent after implementing it for IOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

[image]

No idea why it stopped working. I have implemented several times but this time in android working as expected but not in IOS not even any simulator. If anyone already fixed this issue please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run the debug and make sure the appGroupIdentifier is matched, see this line:

https://github.com/ajith-ab/react-native-receive-sharing-intent/blob/b375726ee9e8f67db116ab8e2b204b2e524aa917/ios/ReceiveSharingIntent.swift#L39

Here is the solution in git:
https://github.com/ajith-ab/react-native-receive-sharing-intent/issues/128

Comment: I've tried it but the result is same.